# How do I throttle appengine-mapreduce on AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce, task-queue

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/ mentions that it can control the speed of execution, but I can't figure out *how*. It would make sense to create a task queue for a mapper job and control the speed from there, but I don't see how to specify which queue to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Thanks to Chris for the pointer, but it took a bit of digging after that to find the exact parameter.)

From http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/UserGuideJava add this to your mapreduce.xml configuration element to limit the number of entities processed per second:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.mapper.inputprocessingrate</name>
    <value>4</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for adding this followup.  You can also use MAPPER_INPUT_PROCESSING_RATE_KEY directly in Java if you're setting up your mapper programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use the Java version myself, but the Python version has a `processing_rate` param that you pass to the mapper spec.

A quick search in the Java source reveals a [MAPPER_INPUT_PROCESSING_RATE_KEY](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/appengine/tools/mapreduce/AppEngineJobContext.java#69) config key, which hopefully points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

For users using python, you may want to search for this variable known as "_DEFAULT_PROCESSING_RATE_PER_SEC" in model.py to increase the default processing rate per second. That worked for me!